# How to replace string between two characters in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

how can I replace the string between the comma and the slash for multiple lines in Sublime? For example with another number

[image: problem]

```
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100],
[0,16,0/1168*100],   [1,16,0/1168*100]
```

[image]

the result

```
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100],
[0,8/1168*100],8/1168*100]
```

here's an [article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) discussing the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Find` -> `Replace...`

Then turn `Regular expression` on and `Replace All`

This is the regular expression you need: `,\d?/`

Comment: I edited the regex. The `?` determines that the minimum amount of characters will fit the `.*` expression.

Comment: You need to include the surrounding characters in the replacement string, since they have been matched by the regular expression. So you can replace with `,9/` for example

Comment: do you see the problem I have? I've pasted the code in my question

Comment: I do. If you expect only numbers where I placed `.*` then you can use `,\d?/`. Otherwise, if you can define in some other way what characters belong there, you can place them in a group, for example `,[0-9]?/`